# Function Implementing Interface vs. Struct Implementing Interface

Tags: go, struct, interface

When implementing an interface with a single method in Go, when should a function be used vs. a struct?

Contrived example: Say I have a logging interface with a single method:

```
type Logger interface {
    Log(message string)
}
```

Option 1: Use a Struct:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Controller struct {
    l     Logger
}
func (c Controller) Run() {
    c.l.Log("done")
}

type Logger interface {
    Log(message string)
}

// Empty struct with method implementing the interface
type LoggerImpl struct {}
func (li LoggerImpl) Log(message string) {
    fmt.Println(message)
}

func main() {
    l := LoggerImpl{}
    c := Controller{l: l}
    c.Run()
}
```

Option #2 - Use a Function

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Controller struct {
    l     Logger
}
func (c Controller) Run() {
    c.l.Log("done")
}

type Logger interface {
    Log(message string)
}

type LoggerAdapter func(message string)

func (lg LoggerAdapter) Log(message string) {
    lg(message)
}

func LogOutput(message string) {
    fmt.Println(message)
}

func main() {
    l := LoggerAdapter(LogOutput)
    c := Controller{l: l}
    c.Run()
}
```

Both work, but it seems like the function option is less resilient to change?

Is there an example of where using a function to implement an interface is a much better idea than using a struct? Or perhaps, downsides to using the struct option in certain scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

You see this in `net/http` with `Handler` and `HandlerFunc`. A function that satisfies an interface is convenient - you can pass in a closure even:

```
c := Controller{
    l: LoggerAdapter(func(message string) {fmt.Println(message)}),
}
```

But a function can't have fields and it's unusual for it to have additional useful methods. Func types like this tend to have a single method that just calls the function.

If you need a more complex type, that's what a struct is, so you can use that.